# views comparison in Database

Tags: oracle, view, ddl

I want to compare views depending on the objects that use this views. 
For example , if an object is used by a view and it has changed recently i want the view to be update just when the object has changed. 
I have some suggestion to use DDL time ; any idea ?
thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "I want the view to be update"? Views are just stored SQL statements which are not executed until SELECTed from. They don't store data anywhere. Are you saying you want to recompile the view if any of the objects upon which the view depends are changed?

Answer (score 0):

Following query may be useful. I used system views `dba_dependencies`, `all_objects` here.
Time1 informs when referenced object was last changed and time2 - when view was last compiled.

```
select d.name, d.referenced_owner, d.referenced_name, 
    o1.last_ddl_time time1, o2.last_ddl_time time2, o2.status
  from dba_dependencies d
    left join all_objects o1 on o1.owner = d.referenced_owner 
      and o1.object_name = d.referenced_name
    left join all_objects o2 on o2.owner = d.owner 
      and o2.object_name = d.name
  where d.owner = 'SCOTT' and d.type = 'VIEW'
```

Test:

```
create table temp as (select dummy col1, dummy col2 from dual);
create view v_temp as select * from temp;
alter table temp drop column col2;  -- <- this invalidates view
```

Query results:

```
NAME      REF_OWNER  REF_NAME  TIME1                TIME2                STATUS
--------  ---------  --------  -------------------  -------------------  -------
V_TEMP    SCOTT      TEMP      2015-03-18 12:23:07  2015-03-18 12:22:10  INVALID
```